# Online storage / sync of large iPhone user databases: perform on server or on device?

Tags: iphone, mysql, sqlite, synchronization, amazon-s3

I'm working on an online user database backup / sync system for a popular SQLite-based iPhone flashcard app; this is fairly large-scale - we could pretty quickly get to 100 million individual flashcard records or more (10,000 users, 10,000 cards each) - and we need to design the system with that sort of scalability in mind. But we're not really in the web-based software business, and at least initially we're not planning to actually give this much of a web interface except for account administration - all of the actual manipulation of user data would occur offline.

So it seems like we have two basic options for how to implement this:

- Perform the sync on the server; store all the users' data in a MySQL database (or a bunch of them as we scale up) and download / upload lists of changes only.
- Perform the sync locally; download the latest version of the database from the server, check for / apply changes on-device, then upload the merged database.

It seems like the local sync option would mean a lot less programming work and much lower hosting costs on our end, but would also mean significantly more bandwidth usage for our users - probably something on the order of 2-4 MB for each sync operation versus a few dozen K for a web-based sync.

Does anybody feel like one of these options is clearly better than the other? Is there some other way of doing this we haven't considered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be way off with the way this works but, as this is synchronisation, why would the local copy of the database not be able to record a list of changes that can then be replicated on the server side? THis only works for a single device of course not syncing multiple devices  to the same data set.

The changes could be noted in various ways: eg you could checksum the records on the iPhone and checksum them again when synchronising, then upload the ones that have changed, deletions would need to be recorded seperately.

Comment: That part isn't what I'm worried about, actually, my big concern is managing that many records on the server side efficiently; this would not be a small MySQL project, and if things grew we could easily get into cluster / shard territory. Whereas if we just retrieved / wrote the whole database files we could probably get by with a small EC2 instance and what by S3 standards is a miniscule amount of file storage.